# HTML - form tag bringing you to a website

Tags: html

How would you do this with form ()?

Make a text box and a Submit button.
You type anything in the textbox and Submit will open a website in your browser with a link of: (example) test.com/TextTheyPutHere.
Basically, if I put 'lol' in the textbox, it would open a website test.com/lol.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script>
function newDoc() {
window.location.assign("http://www.yourVeryOwnSitez.com/"+document.myForm.myDestination.value)
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" name="myForm">
<input type="text" name="myDestination">
<input type="button" value="Gogogo" onclick="newDoc()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then edit line 7 and put your particular url in the place of "www.yourVeryOwnSitez.com".

Comment: Thanks this helped. Found out you need Javascript for that now. Also I'm new to stackoverflow so I'm not sure if I marked the answer as correct, the tick on the left of your comment is green so I think I did it right. Thanks anyway!

Comment: One question, any way to make the text box bigger?

Comment: Ahah yes... some options. If you just want to have a wider textbox just play with "size" property. So, try this on your code: `<input type="text" name="myDestination" size="80">`. But I recommend you test in various browsers and platforms, cause the same value can cause different results. if you want different fonts, colors, sizes inside textbox then maybe better google for it. There are many options, all of them based on CSS. Luck.